# Draw a triangle that encloses points

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following TikZ code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,fill=red] (1) at (4,7.5)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=green ] (2) at (8,8)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=blue] (4) at (5,7)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=violet] (3) at (8,5)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=orange] (5) at (9,4.5)  {};
    
    \node[circle,fill=red] (11) at (2,4)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=green ] (22) at (4,5)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=blue] (44) at (5,4)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=violet] (33) at (1,8)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=orange] (55) at (3,6.5)  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That produce the following

[image]

I want to draw two triangles as follows

[image]

How we can draw those?

Comment: Do you want those triangles to be automatically computed even if you modifiy the position of your initial points or do you want to add those triangles to this specific drawing?

Comment: I want add those triangles to this specific drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I compile this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,fill=red] (1) at (4,7.5)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=green ] (2) at (8,8)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=blue] (4) at (5,7)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=violet] (3) at (8,5)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=orange] (5) at (9,4.5)  {};
    \draw[thick,color=red] (10,3)--(8,9)--(2.5,8)--(10,3);
    
    \node[circle,fill=red] (11) at (2,4)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=green ] (22) at (4,5)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=blue] (44) at (5,4)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=violet] (33) at (1,8)  {};
    \node[circle,fill=orange] (55) at (3,6.5)  {};
    \draw[thick,color=red] (-1,10)--(9.5,3)--(2,3)--(-1,10);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

what I get is this:

[image]

Comment: Very very good. +1.